# Writing a function which compares two trees and returns true if they are equal in structure and in value and false otherwise

Tags: ruby, binary-tree

Given two trees, I want to return true if they are equal in structure and in value and false otherwise.

Given the following class:

```
class TreeNode
  attr_accessor :val, :left, :right

  def initialize val, left = nil, right = nil
    @val = val
    @left = left
    @right = right
  end
end
```

complete the function

`def binary_tree_compare(a, b)`

My research led me to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733986/2-binary-trees-are-equal-or-not). I have tried the ruby solution but to no avail
Below is the code I have tried so far:

```
def binary_tree_compare a, b
  for_check << [a, b]   

  while a,b = for_check.shift  
    return false unless a.children.count == b.children.count 
    break if a.children.empty?

    a_children = a.children.sort 
    b_children = b.children.sort     
    return false unless a_children == b_children  

    0.upto(a_children.count - 1) do |i|
      for_check << [a_children[i], b_children[i]]  
    end
  end
  return true
end
```

### I expect the output to be true if TreeNodes a and b are equal in structure and in value and false otherwise.

I am getting a syntax error and this is the stack trace:

````
  solution.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_do_cond or ';' or '\n'
    while a,b = for_check.shift  
           ^
  solution.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_cond, expecting keyword_end
  ...0.upto(a_children.count - 1) do |i|
  ...                             ^~
  olution.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
    end
    ^~~ ```
````

Comment: Please define a tree as a Ruby object, as you have done for tree nodes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland how exactly do I go about that?

Comment: I see. Trees are defined by their top nodes, `a` and `b`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland @ggorlen solution below that I accepted as the answer worked as it considers the nodes `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's fix the syntax/logic errors:

1. Use parentheses to enforce operator precedence:

   ```
   while a,b = for_check.shift
   ```

   should be

   ```
   while (a, b = for_check.shift)
   ```
2. The array `for_check` doesn't exist when you try to push an element onto it.

   ```
   for_check << [a, b]
   ```

   should be

   ```
   for_check = [a, b]
   ```

Secondly, your code doesn't seem to have much to do with the problem presented (although the simultaneous search using both nodes in a stack is the right idea). For one, the `TreeNode` class you've shown here has no `children` member array. The intention of that code is to handle general trees with `n` children as well as to ignore the ordering of those children, two characteristics that are not part of the problem you're facing.

My recommendation is to re-approach the problem assuming a binary tree and ordering of children matters as well as their values.

If you'd like a spoiler, try the following recursive logic (iterative works too, as you're doing with an explicit stack, and it's instructional to write both):

1. If either root is nil, make sure the other root is also nil and return. We've either reached mutually nil leaves in both trees, which is valid, or one is a leaf and the other isn't, which is invalid. This is the base case.
2. If both roots are non-nil, ensure they have the same value, then recursively validate both left and right subtrees.

Here's the code:

```
class TreeNode
  attr_accessor :val, :left, :right

  def initialize val, left = nil, right = nil
    @val = val
    @left = left
    @right = right
  end
end

def binary_tree_compare a, b
  return !a && !b if !a || !b
  return false if a.val != b.val
  return binary_tree_compare(a.left, b.left) &&
         binary_tree_compare(a.right, b.right)
end

a = TreeNode.new(
  1, TreeNode.new(
    2, TreeNode.new(4)
  ), TreeNode.new(3)
)
b = TreeNode.new(
  1, TreeNode.new(
    2, TreeNode.new(4)
  ), TreeNode.new(3)
)

puts binary_tree_compare a, b
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def binary_tree_compare(a_top_node, b_top_node)
  convert(a_top_node) == convert(b_top_node)
end

def convert(node)
  { node.val => recurse(node) }
end

def recurse(node)
  return nil if node.left.nil? && node.right.nil?
  [node.left, node.right].each_with_object({}) do |n, h|
    h[n.val] = recurse(n) unless n.nil?
  end
end
```

**Example**

Let's first create two binary trees. They will look like the following.

[image]

These trees are seen to be equal in structure.

This is your class `TreeNode`.

```
class TreeNode
  attr_accessor :val, :left, :right

  def initialize val, left = nil, right = nil
    @val = val
    @left = left
    @right = right
  end
end
```

In addition, I will create a class `Tree`.

```
class Tree
  attr_reader :top_node, :name_to_node

  def initialize(top_node_name)
    @top_node = TreeNode.new(top_node_name)
    @name_to_node = { top_node_name=>@top_node }
  end

  def add_node(name, parent, side)
    node = TreeNode.new(name)
    name_to_node[name] = node
    if side == :left
      name_to_node[parent].left = node
    else
      name_to_node[parent].right = node
    end
  end
end
```

We can now construct the two binary trees shown in the drawing.

```
a = Tree.new(1)
a.add_node(2, 1, :left)
a.add_node(3, 1, :right)
a.add_node(4, 2, :left)
a.add_node(5, 3, :right)

a.top_node
  #=> #<TreeNode:0x000059e97fa499e0 @val=1,
  #     @left=#<TreeNode:0x000059e97fa508d0 @val=2,
  #       @left=#<TreeNode:0x000059e97fa719b8 @val=4, @left=nil, @right=nil>,
  #       @right=nil>,
  #     @right=#<TreeNode:0x000059e97fa66900 @val=3,
  #       @left=nil,
  #       @right=#<TreeNode:0x000059e97fa7cb60 @val=5, @left=nil, @right=nil>>>
```

```
b = Tree.new(1)
b.add_node(2, 1, :right)
b.add_node(3, 1, :left)
b.add_node(4, 2, :right)
b.add_node(5, 3, :left)

b.top_node
  #=> #<TreeNode:0x000059e97fa99b48 @val=1,
  #     @left=#<TreeNode:0x000059e97fab5758 @val=3,
  #       @left=#<TreeNode:0x000059e97faf4cf0 @val=5, @left=nil, @right=nil>,
  #       @right=nil>,
  #     @right=#<TreeNode:0x000059e97faaf9e8 @val=2,
  #       @left=nil,
  #       @right=#<TreeNode:0x000059e97fac0040 @val=4, @left=nil, @right=nil>>>
```

Now determine if these two binary trees are equal in structure.

```
binary_tree_compare(a.top_node, b.top_node)
  #=> true
```

**Explanation**

`convert` returns the following hashes.

```
convert(a.top_node)
  #=> {1=>{2=>{4=>nil}, 3=>{5=>nil}}} 
convert(b.top_node)
  #=> {1=>{3=>{5=>nil}, 2=>{4=>nil}}}
```

These hashes, which are 1-1 mappings of the binary trees, are clearly equal even though their keys are not in the same order.